# Localhost error when trying to use XAMPP to connect to SID

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to learn MySQL. I have installed XAMPP and have set up users in phpMyAdmin. All of the folders appear to be in the correct place and localhost does work, however I am getting an error when trying to connect to a specific folder.

I have watched a few videos, but they have no addressed the particular issue I am having.

> Warning: dir(../db,../db): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php on line 371
>
> Warning: dir(../db): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php on line 371
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function read() on bool
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php:373 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php(139): database_select_list(':memory:') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php(64): _init() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php on line 373

This should be allowing me to connect to SID so I can do the MySQL exercises. I have double-checked the path and it should be correct.

Comment: Somehow I do not think it has anything to do with phpMyAdmin. It looks like the error comes from your own code written in PHP, which you have not shown us.